# How to step through a loop with pry and view the value of an iterator?

Tags: ruby, pry

I inserted `binding.pry` into my Ruby program and am trying to view the value of an iterator at each iteration of my loop:

```
require 'pry'

def longest_palindrome s
  max_palindrome_len = 0
  for i in (0..s.length)
    binding.pry
    for j in (i..s.length)
      binding.pry
      substr = s[i..j]
      if substr == substr.reverse && substr.length > max_palindrome_len
        max_palindrome_len = substr.length
      end
    end
  end
  return max_palindrome_len
end

longest_palindrome "racer"
```

I want to view the values for `i` and `j` at each iteration in the loop.

I'm sure I'm just missing something here, but I haven't been able to figure out what to do from the documentation.

Comment: What *did* you try? What was the result of trying?

Comment: The usual way is just to add `puts` statements. For example, insert the line `puts "i = #{i}"` after `for i in (0..s.length)` and `"puts "  j = #{j}"` after `for j in (i..s.length)`. (Note that I indented the latter `puts` a couple of spaces to make it easier to read.)...

Comment: ... [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-tap) can be handy as well. For example, suppose you had `arr.group_by.with_index {...}` and wished to examine the elements of the enumerator `arr.group_by`. You could do that as follows: `arr.group_by.tap { |enum| puts "arr.group_by.to_a = #{enum.to_a}" }.with index {...}`. This works because tap returns its receiver and I've not altered the receiver in `tap`'s block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can type `p i` and `p j` to manually inspect them.

That'd make me crazy though, so I'd insert `puts i` and `puts j` temporarily.

Don't use `for` loops with Ruby. Instead we use `each` or `upto`, `downto` or `times`, depending on our purpose. Also, explicit `return` statements aren't needed at the end of a method unless you are forcing the code to exit early.

I'd write your code something like:

```
require 'pry'

def longest_palindrome(s)
  max_palindrome_len = 0

  s.length.times do |i|
    binding.pry
    i.upto(s.length) do |j|
      binding.pry
      substr = s[i..j]
      if substr == substr.reverse && substr.length > max_palindrome_len
        max_palindrome_len = substr.length
      end
    end
  end

  max_palindrome_len
end

longest_palindrome "racer"
```