# How to step through a loop with PRY and view the value of an iterator in a terminal session?

Tags: ruby, debugging, pry

I have exactly the same question as "j doe" (original question is here: [How to step through a loop with pry and view the value of an iterator?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35323710/4394031) ), the question was not really answered though. I want to ask people who actually **use Pry for debugging** to explain how to step into loops and evaluate expressions as loop happens.

I read documentation, checked help files in terminal, watched YouTubes but sadly I do not get it. Couple of times I was able to "get into the loop" by chance I think.
What i have:

- I use a single ruby file,
- on my system I have previously installed gems `byebug (8.2.1, 3.5.1, 3.4.0)`; `pry (0.10.3, 0.10.1)` and `pry-rails (0.3.4, 0.3.2)`.
- I have `require 'pry'` at the top of the script and
- I use `binding.pry` to set break points.

This is what I did in Terminal using example from the included question. I get so far, but what is my next step? How do I actually *make* the next move to step through the loop and see value of variable I watch?

```
Last login: Thu Oct 20 18:21:07 on ttys000
INB:~ LearnEnough$ pry
[1] pry(main)> def longest_palindrome s
[1] pry(main)*   max_palindrome_len = 0
[1] pry(main)*   for i in (0..s.length)
[1] pry(main)*     binding.pry
[1] pry(main)*     for j in (i..s.length)
[1] pry(main)*       binding.pry
[1] pry(main)*       substr = s[i..j]
[1] pry(main)*       if substr == substr.reverse && substr.length >     max_palindrome_len

[1] pry(main)*         max_palindrome_len = substr.length
[1] pry(main)*       end
[1] pry(main)*     end
[1] pry(main)*   end
[1] pry(main)*   return max_palindrome_len
[1] pry(main)* end
=> :longest_palindrome
[2] pry(main)> longest_palindrome "racer"

From: (pry) @ line 4 Object#longest_palindrome:

     1: def longest_palindrome s
     2:   max_palindrome_len = 0
     3:   for i in (0..s.length)
 =>  4:     binding.pry
     5:     for j in (i..s.length)
     6:       binding.pry
     7:       substr = s[i..j]
     8:       if substr == substr.reverse && substr.length > max_palindrome_len
     9:         max_palindrome_len = substr.length
    10:       end
    11:     end
    12:   end
    13:   return max_palindrome_len
    14: end

[1] pry(main)> watch i
Watching i
watch: i => 0
[2] pry(main)> watch j
Watching j
watch: j => nil
[3] pry(main)>
```

Answer (score 0):

`pry-debugger` and `pry-nav` are now not supported in Ruby and you need them to perform this actions. I need to use `pry-byebug` for this.

Here is a very short and useful video on how to use pry in loops:

https://youtu.be/dbllOus430c